# Increase number with PHP (the first one is without a number)

Tags: php

I have a slide that uses caption (NivoSlider). So I'm using this code

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('sub_field_1'); ?>" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
```

What I need is simple, but I really don't know how to do it:

The first image will be #htmlcaption 
The second image will be #htmlcaption1 
The third image will be #htmlcaption2 
...

How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Do you want the number added to the title value or the src?

Comment: do you have control over these names? if so, I suggest a more computer-friendly and logical number scheme... like, start at 0 or 1 and don't have the first one omit a digit.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
for ($i=0; $i < ...; $i++) {
    echo '#htmlcaption' . ($i == 0 ? '' : $i) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Basically what you'll want to do is iterate over a total number of elements you want and then simply insert the actual counter into the text of the element:

```
<?php

$total_count = 3;
for ( $i = 0; $i < total_count; $i++ ){ 
  $additinal_parameter = ( $i > 0 )? $i : '';
  echo '<img ... title="#htmlcaption'. $additinal_parameter .'" />'
}

?>
```

Notice that there is an additional check if the iterator (`$i`) is larger than zero because we don't want zero to  be appended.

This will output something like this:

```
<img ... title="#htmlcaption" />
<img ... title="#htmlcaption1" />
<img ... title="#htmlcaption2" />
```

Comment: You could simply start `$i` at one and iterate over the last two only. No need for the nested if statement.

Comment: in the loop body you only output if $i > 0. What about the first one?

Comment: @TGO - According to the OP - the first element has no additions so zero is not inserted.

Comment: @Lix ok now you fixed it. Tje original answer started the output when i was 1

Comment: @Lix I am on mobile and it seemed to me as this answer was edited. Never mind though

Answer (score -1):

What would you think about using the following?

```
<img src="<?php the_sub_field('sub_field_1'); ?>" alt="" title="#htmlcaption<?php echo $htmlcaption_i++; ?>" />
```

The `$htmlcaption_i++` means that the value will be printed and then incremented. The first time the printout will be `''`, the second time `'1'`, and so on.

It is recommendet to set `$htmlcaption_i` in the beginning of the page

```
<?php $htmlcaption_i = 0; ?>
```

Comment: I don't feel that using incremental operators is good practice - especially within an echo command. [pThese operators can get pretty confusing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) and lot's of developers simply don't know all the angles of using them. I prefer to stay away from them wherever I can - this is one such place I wouldn't use them.

Comment: @Lix Ok. As I see it, the OP's PHP knowledge is limited and this is the easiest solution to implement.

Comment: Othwerwise you can end up with loop inside a loop. If for example, the img's are generated in while loop, why would you need a for loop when you simply increment a variable each time the while iterate?

Comment: @blo - doesn't mean I should give less advice. It's the perfect situation to give a full explanation and not to use shortcut methods.

Comment: @Lix I see your point, however the OP seems to use the code inside the HTML code without much knowledge of PHP. You are right, a for loop is nicer.

Comment: @Lix, even in simple for loop, you have `for($i=0;$i<x;$i++)`, don't you? I never heard that incremental operators are pretty confusing. They have their practical use, you can use `$i+1` for example,  but these operators tell when the increment should start - pre or post increment.

Comment: @ric - when answering questions here, I'll always try and match my answer to the level of the OP while still trying to include as much useful info. In this case, I believe that if you want to use the incremental operator, you should include an explanation of how and why it is used. In this explanation you would have to go off on a tangent and explain pre vs post incrementing etc, etc which, IMO would distract from the main point - to increment a value. When in doubt - take the easier form that needs less explanation.

Comment: Unless there is a specific need to use those operators, I'd always default back to `$i += 1`.